# PostgresSQL FuzzySearch

Tags: postgresql

I am trying fuzzy search on PostgresSQL and have PostgreSQL 12.5 version installed.

After enabling extension:
`CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm with schema dev;`

I am trying to execute below SQL
`select *  from dev.hello_world a where 'Hello' % ANY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(a.name, ' '))`

SQL Error [42883]: ERROR: operator does not exist: unknown % text
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I have tried this before and used to work. Not able to get reference from document for change.

Comment: What happens if you do: `...'Hello'::text % ANY(STRING_TO_ARRAY(a.name, ' '))`?

Comment: If dev is not in your search_path, you need to fully qualify the operater name.  Which you can do by using `OPERATOR(dev.%)`